# PyQt6 Add a widget with a layout to the scroll area, but it can't be scrolled

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6

I tried to add multiple widgets, which contain a vertical layout to split text and buttons and a horizontal layout to split buttons, into a scroll area.

In my expectation, all widgets should be one by one, and if there are too many widgets, the scroll area can be scrolled.

I use a container vertical layout to contain all the widgets I tried to put in the scroll area, and then I put the container layout into a container widget. After that, I set a widget in the scroll area with a container widget, but the results weren't what I expected; instead, all the widgets in the layout collapsed together, and I could barely see the words, and I couldn't scroll the area either.

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QSizePolicy, QLayout
from UI import comment  # Assuming you have saved the form in a file named comment_form.py

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Scroll Area Example")
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)

# Create a container widget and layout to hold the forms
container_widget = QWidget()
container_layout = QVBoxLayout()
container_layout.setSpacing(10)  # Adjust the spacing as needed

for i in range(5):
    # Create instances of the Ui_Form
    form = comment.Ui_Form()
    form_widget = QWidget()
    form.setupUi(form_widget)
    form.Comment_label.setWordWrap(True)  # Allow text to wrap to multiple lines
    form.Comment_label.setFixedWidth(300)
    form.Comment_label.setText("Test message in scroll area" * i)
    form_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)  # Set the size policy
    container_layout.addWidget(form_widget)

container_layout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SizeConstraint.SetMaximumSize)
container_widget.setLayout(container_layout)

# Create a scroll area and set the container widget as its content
scroll_area = QScrollArea()
scroll_area.setMinimumSize(350, 300)
scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)  # Allows the scroll area to resize its contents

scroll_area.setWidget(container_widget)

window_layout = QVBoxLayout()
window_layout.addWidget(scroll_area)
window.setLayout(window_layout)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
   <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Discuss</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>354</width>
     <height>81</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="sizeConstraint">
     <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="Author_label">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Arial</family>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="Comment_label">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Arial</family>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <property name="sizeConstraint">
       <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="Floor_Time_label">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="palette">
         <palette>
          <active>
           <colorrole role="WindowText">
            <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
             <color alpha="255">
              <red>90</red>
              <green>90</green>
              <blue>90</blue>
             </color>
            </brush>
           </colorrole>
          </active>
          <inactive>
           <colorrole role="WindowText">
            <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
             <color alpha="255">
              <red>90</red>
              <green>90</green>
              <blue>90</blue>
             </color>
            </brush>
           </colorrole>
          </inactive>
          <disabled>
           <colorrole role="WindowText">
            <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
             <color alpha="255">
              <red>120</red>
              <green>120</green>
              <blue>120</blue>
             </color>
            </brush>
           </colorrole>
          </disabled>
         </palette>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Arial</family>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>B1, 3 days ago</string>
        </property>
        <property name="scaledContents">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="Reply_pushButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Arial</family>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Reply</string>
        </property>
        <property name="autoDefault">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="flat">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="Delete_pushButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Arial</family>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Delete</string>
        </property>
        <property name="autoDefault">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="default">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="flat">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: comment widget]
[image: Example of scroll area]

Comment: It seems like you didn't set a proper layout for the form in Designer, you just dragged one from the widget box, but that's insufficient (the top level window *must* have a layout). Please include its ui code. Also, you already have a container widget, just add it to the scroll area, that further `scroll_content_widget` is useless and redundant.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for replying, after I pull comment layout into a vertical layout, the buttons are still covered, and scroll area doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you probably just added another layout from the widget box instead of setting a main layout as already said. Look at the top level widget (`Form` in your case) in the object inspector of Designer, it most certainly has a small red "forbidden" icon, which means that you didn't set a top level layout. Remove all widgets from their current layouts, remove those layouts, right click on an empty area of the form and select "Lay Out Vertically" from the bottom "Lay out" submenu. If you still don't understand, please provide the actual ui file code, not the pyuic generated one.

Comment: @musicamante But once I remove layouts and widget, right-clicked menu didn't allow me to choose "Lay Out Vertically" option.

Comment: You don't have to completely remove the widgets, you have to remove them *from that layout*: just drag them outside of that "vertical layout" and put them anywhere within the window, then remove that useless layout and apply a real one using the context menu.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot!!! It works perfectly as what I expected

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration on my own, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164117/custom-widget-in-scrollarea-is-being-squashed) which inspired me.
Then, I add this line into the code, and it works!

```py
form_widget.setMinimumHeight(65+form.Comment_label.sizeHint().height())
```

This code represent first label height + button height + comment label height, and can automatically fetch how high comment label is to adapt the widget since `wordWrap` is True.

Comment: This is not a valid solution, because it uses arbitrary sizes that don't take into account aspects like font scaling or size requirements from the current style. The *only* correct solution is to properly set a main layout for the form element.